# How to fix "no match for operator+" in C++?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, operator-overloading

I am writing a class that overloads some basic operators. I have written other classes using the same concepts and syntax, and they work fine, but now I am getting an error regarding my operator+ function specifically for this class. When the '+' operator is not written in my client program everything compiles fine, but when I use the '+' operator to initialize the data of an object with the sum of the data in the first two objects the error is produced.

I have viewed the operator overloading FAQ, and some other similar questions on this website, but none have helped me. Namely because the error does not seem to arise on a different computer. I sent the code to my professor who was stumped as he could not reproduce the error that I am getting.

My code is in three separate files: mystring.h mystring.cpp and simpleclient.cpp. I will include the relevant code from each file as the rest of the code should irrelevant, but if you would like me to include the entire file I can do that.

mystring.h:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#ifndef MYSTRING_H
#define MYSTRING_H
namespace cs_mystring{
    class MyString {
        public:
            MyString(const char* = "");
            MyString(const MyString& right);
            ~MyString();
            MyString operator=(const MyString& right);
            friend MyString operator+(const MyString& left, const MyString& right);
            //OTHER FUNCTION DECLARATIONS
        private:
            char* data;
    };
}
#endif
```

mystring.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>
#include "mystring.h"

namespace cs_mystring{
    //DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR
    MyString::MyString(const char* init){
        data = new char[strlen(init) + 1];
        strcpy(data, init);
    }
    //COPY CONSTRUCTOR
    MyString::MyString(const MyString& right){
        data = new char[strlen(right.data) + 1];
        strcpy(data, right.data);
    }
    //DESTRUCTOR
    MyString::~MyString(){
        delete[] data;
    }
    //TODO
    MyString operator+(const MyString& left, const MyString& right){
        MyString temp;

        const int bufferSize = sizeof(left.data) + sizeof(right.data) + 2;
        char buffer[bufferSize];
        strcpy(buffer, left.data);
        strcat(buffer, right.data);
        temp = MyString(buffer);

        return temp;
    }
    //ASSIGNMENT OPERATOR
    MyString MyString::operator=(const MyString& right){
        if(this != &right){
            delete[] data; //remove the value stored in the heap
            data = new char[strlen(right.data) + 1]; //allocate memory for the new value
            strcpy(data, right.data); //copy the right-hand value into the new memory
        }
        return *this; //return the left hand object with the new value in the pointed-to memory location
    }

    //OTHER FUNCTION IMPLEMENTATIONS

}
```

simpleclient.cpp:

```cpp
#include "mystring.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>      // for toupper()
#include <string>     
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cs_mystring;

int main(){

    //Simplest way to produce the error
    MyString a = MyString("Hello, ");
    MyString b = MyString("World!");
    MyString c = a + b;//Error is produced here
}
```

The idea here is that the data member for MyString c would contain "Hello, World!".

I compile and execute the program with the following commands:

```
$ cd ~/Directory/with/the/files
$ g++ mystring.h mystring.cpp simpleclient.cpp -o exec
$ ./exec
```

When the client program contains the errant code, I receive the following output from the terminal after the second command:

```
$ g++ mystring.cpp simpleclient.cpp -o exec
simpleclient.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
simpleclient.cpp:16:20: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘cs_mystring::MyString’ and ‘cs_mystring::MyString’)
     MyString c = a + b;
                    ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from mystring.h:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:334:5: note: candidate: template<class _Iterator> std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator> std::operator+(typename std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>::difference_type, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
     operator+(typename reverse_iterator<_Iterator>::difference_type __n,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:334:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
simpleclient.cpp:16:22: note:   ‘cs_mystring::MyString’ is not derived from ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’
     MyString c = a + b;
                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from mystring.h:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:4783:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     operator+(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:4783:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
simpleclient.cpp:16:22: note:   ‘cs_mystring::MyString’ is not derived from ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’
     MyString c = a + b;
                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:53:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from mystring.h:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.tcc:1151:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const _CharT*, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     operator+(const _CharT* __lhs,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.tcc:1151:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
simpleclient.cpp:16:22: note:   mismatched types ‘const _CharT*’ and ‘cs_mystring::MyString’
     MyString c = a + b;
                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:53:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from mystring.h:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.tcc:1167:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(_CharT, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     operator+(_CharT __lhs, const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __rhs)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.tcc:1167:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
simpleclient.cpp:16:22: note:   ‘cs_mystring::MyString’ is not derived from ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’
     MyString c = a + b;
                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from mystring.h:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:4820:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)
     operator+(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:4820:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
simpleclient.cpp:16:22: note:   ‘cs_mystring::MyString’ is not derived from ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’
     MyString c = a + b;
                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from mystring.h:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:4836:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, _CharT)
     operator+(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs, _CharT __rhs)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:4836:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
simpleclient.cpp:16:22: note:   ‘cs_mystring::MyString’ is not derived from ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’
     MyString c = a + b;
                      ^
```

If you can explain what this error and the output means and how to fix it, that will solve my problem.

Comment: *that will solve my problem.* -- Until you try `a = b;` in your program.  You're missing a user-defined assignment operator.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error on my system with the code that you've provided. Are you 100% positive that the contents of the files are what you think they are? For example, do you have multiple copies of the files lying around and compile the wrong one? Also, what version of g++ do you have?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I have the assignment operator in my file should I include it in this post?

Comment: @templatetypedef I sent the actual files themselves to my professor and he was also unable to reproduce this error. I do not have any copies of these files in my directory. Here is the g++ --version output:                                                          $ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: @BrandynG `temp = MyString(buffer);` -- This uses the assignment operator, which you didn't post.  When posting classes such as ones like this (manage resources), you need to post *all* of the methods that could be used in the management of those resources, not just some methods and leave out others.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have updated the post to include the declaration and implementation of the operator= function. Please let me know if there is anything else I should include.

Comment: @BrandynG Off topic, but this -- `const int bufferSize = sizeof(left.data) + sizeof(right.data) + 2;`  -- is a bug, since `data` is only a pointer.  You can't use `sizeof` here to determine the length of the strings.  You need to rethink how you're implementing `operator +`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You are correct in that off-topic bug. I have a separate int length() const function that simply returns a call to strlen(data). I have not changed the appropriate code to use that function though, so I did not include it in this post.

Comment: @BrandynG [Cannot duplicate](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/152a7af8f01b5ce9).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I updated the bufferSize variable to use the length() function, but it did not have an effect on the error. While the original implementation does not allocate an appropriate amount of memory, it does not seem to be why this error is being produced. Do you think the only solution would be to reinstall g++?

Comment: @BrandynG  Take the code I posted at the link and compile it.  If it compiles, there is no need to reinstall the compiler.   The issue is somewhere else, like you are using a stale header file that doesn't have that definition for `operator +`.

Comment: @BrandynG [Similar error if operator+ is missing](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f56f1da86af5cdfe).  You need to ensure you're using the proper files, and not old ones.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for helping. This is strange but after compiling the mystring.h file in a separate command from the .cpp files the error went away. Is that how it is supposed to be done? I have never ran into this sort of problem before when compiling all the files at once.

Comment: I do not know your environment setup, but the usual command-line to compile multiple files is to specify all the source files in the command, i.e. `g++ file1.cpp file2.cpp ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by compiling the .h file in a separate command from the .cpp files.